# Sum value of elements and update field Mongo db

Tags: mongodb

How Can I sum price on array "Elemets" and set on Document field Value? 
I know how to do It in sql but I,m beginner in mongo.

```
{
    "Document": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Type": "FV",
            "Number": 34521,
            "Year": 2020,
            "Date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",               
            "Value": 27.68,

            "Elements": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "DocumentId": 1,
                    "ProductId": 1,

                    "Quantity": 5.00,
                    "Price": 17.50,
                    "Task": 0.23
                },
              {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "DocumentId": 1,
                    "ProductId": 2,

                    "Quantity": 3.00,
                    "Price": 24.50,
                    "Task": 0.23
                },
            ]
        },
```

Comment: is this a single document in colletion

Comment: no I have 8 documents with different numbers of elements  and I want do sum  Price on array "Elements" and set field "Value" on  documents

Comment: Is `Document` a field of your document or is it an sample of your array of documents? i.e. Is `Document` or `Elements` your top level field

Comment: share full snippet of mongo query result

Comment: Document is top level field

Comment: Now value  = 27.68  and i want to write update to change  to this value = 17.50 + 24,50 so  value should be = 42

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB 4.2, you can use `$reduce` to calculate the sum in the pipeline form of `update`.